# Rigidbody randomly speeds up when a list is modified (Unity)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I was making a game about eggdogs who can shoot each other to play with my brother(he likes egg dogs so much for some reason). It was going to be private. And it was going to have an auto aim mechanic which would aim to the nearest enemy. The idea was when a player gets in your range using a trigger collider, the player would be added to a target list and then a method would calculate the nearest player.

I wrote some code and it worked almost perfectly, however when the list is modified, the player randomly speeds up. I have no idea why this happens. I tried commenting out a lot of code and modifying the list from somewhere else and it seems to happen only when the list is modified. Here is some code:

This is my main EggDog controller:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EggdogController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator an;
    public int PlayerNo;
    public float speed;

    public Transform pickupParent;
    public Transform currentPickupTarget;

    public List<Transform> targetList = new List<Transform>();
    public Transform currentTarget;

    void Awake(){
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        an = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update(){
        Move();
        Boba();
        PickTarget();
    }

    void Move(){
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        move.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal" + PlayerNo.ToString());
        move.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical" + PlayerNo.ToString());
        rb.velocity = move*speed*Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void Boba(){
        an.SetBool("longing", Input.GetAxisRaw("Boba" + PlayerNo.ToString()) == 1);       
    }

    void PickTarget()
    {
        if(targetList.ToArray().Length > 0)
        {
            float currentDistance = -69f;
            foreach (Transform potato in targetList.ToArray())
            {
                float thistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, potato.position);
                if(currentDistance == -69f)
                {
                    currentDistance = thistance;
                    currentTarget = potato;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(currentDistance > thistance)
                    {
                        currentTarget = potato;
                    }
                }
            }          
        }
    }   
}
```

And this is my EggdogTriggerTarget script, attached to a child object with a trigger collider :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EggdogTriggerTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    EggdogController parent;

    private void Awake()
    {
        parent = transform.parent.GetComponent<EggdogController>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            parent.targetList.Add(other.transform);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            bool exists = false;
            foreach (Transform tr in parent.targetList.ToArray())
            {
                if (tr == other.transform)
                {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
            if (exists)
            {
                parent.targetList.Remove(other.transform);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error messages or anything online. I would be happy if you could help.

Comment: Your `rigidbody.velocity` is only affected by `Input`. No connection with the list of targets. Anyway, you need to modify rigidbodies in `FixedUpdate()` and you shouldn't modify velocity explicitly, consider using `Rigidbody.AddForce()`

Comment: @luvjungle Thanks! Transfering my Move() method to fixed update fixed it!

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. Please mark it as helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rigidbody.velocity` is only affected by `Input`. No connection with the list of targets. Anyway, you need to modify rigidbodies in `FixedUpdate()` and you shouldn't modify velocity explicitly, consider using `Rigidbody.AddForce()`